# how to tracking event requests in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6.2

I use liferay6.2.0 CE.
I enabled UBT(user behavior traking) for monitor access user(login/logout) but this can't monitor event requests.
I want to track event requests in liferay without use Google Analytics . 
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytics Packages like Google Analytics are typically deployed on a separate server, as this will neatly separate read (potentially massive for a high-traffic site) from write operations (keeping track of each request).

That being said, there are exceptions to this rule, and - as always - it depends:

If you're just interested in login/logout events, you can easily inject hooks into Liferay, keeping track of this in a form that makes most sense for you.

There's an Audit Plugin for Liferay EE (not your version, sorry) which will keep track of a configurable amount of events.

There's session tracking (configuration with [live.users.enabled](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Live%20Users)) which will make the logged in users available to the Administrator

And finally, you can take a look at the Audience Targetting App ([CE](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/43707761), [EE](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/43707691)), which will build user profiles through various criteria. Lots of documentation and webinars available for this new toy.

Whatever you do: You're on a version of Liferay that has 3 more large updates (we're on 6.2.3, which is 6.2 GA4 while you're on GA1) and you should seriously consider upgrading to stay on top of all the fixes that got released. Only this will get the latest security fixes.